Problem installing scipy/matlab sagemath package (via WSL)
I'm trying to install Sagemath on my computer (running with Windows 10) using WSL. I run "make" in the sage directory, and everything is fine until the step 1004 in installing scipy package.
The installation "froze", the hard drive seems to be reading continuously while the processor seems not to be working. I thus waited for 15mn and keyboard interrupted the make command. The following error was displayed:
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install] Traceback (most recent call last):`
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main`
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 449, in <module>`
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     main(sys.argv[1:], 'python -m build')
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 429, in main
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     built = build_call(
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]             ^^^^^^^^^^^
[python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 238, in build_package
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     out = _build(isolation, srcdir, outdir, distribution, config_settings, skip_dependency_check, installer)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ```

 

[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 172, in _build`
`[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return _build_in_current_env(srcdir, outdir, distribution, config_settings, skip_dependency_check)`
`[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]  `          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/__main__.py", line 157, in _build_in_current_env
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return builder.build(distribution, outdir, config_settings or {})
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/_builder.py", line 283, in build
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return self._call_backend(f'build_{distribution}', output_directory, config_settings, **kwargs)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/build/_builder.py", line 330, in _call_backend
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     basename: str = callback(outdir, config_settings, **kwargs)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 209, in build_wheel
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return self._call_hook('build_wheel', {
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 311, in _call_hook
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     self._subprocess_runner(
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 59, in default_subprocess_runner
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     check_call(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 408, in check_call
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 391, in call
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1264, in wait
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 2053, in _wait
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]   File "/home/a***/sage/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.12.4/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 2011, in _try_wait
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]     (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[scipy-1.12.0] [spkg-install] KeyboardInterrupt
[scipy-1.12.0] ************************************************************************
[scipy-1.12.0] Error installing package scipy-1.12.0
[scipy-1.12.0] ************************************************************************`

Could you help me to resolve this problem ?
Bests
Free some memory in the hard drive (15Go available)
Wait 15mn
Same results
